# Finding prime numbers in intervals bounded by consecutive $c$-powers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a positive number $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every prime number $p \in \mathbb{N}$ it is true that the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid p^c < n < (p + 1)^c \}$ contains at least one prime number for all $c > b$?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The answer is positive. In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44239555?seq=1) there is a proof, namely with $b=12/5>2$. For $b=2$ the problem is open.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the reference!